# How to add excerpt in woocommerce for product title while displaying products in a page or category loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, hook-woocommerce

Facing issues with the list of product showing in a page
http://bubblz.in/test-2/ 
The name of the product in a first row will effect the product in the second row.
Anyone know how to sort out this issue else any idea about adding excerpt for product name length?

Comment: what is affecting?

Comment: Typo error i just corrected it, have a look in to the link you might know the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in functions.php

```
add_filter('the_title', 'single_product_page_title', 10, 2);

function single_product_page_title($title, $id) {
    if(is_product_category() || is_page() ) {                
        $title = mb_strimwidth($title, 0, 15, '...');
        return $title;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, can you please have a look on this site https://www.oyehappy.com/surprises/premium/birthday/ , in the second row the product "Cabana, Candles and Cu..." like this am searching for.

Comment: I have updated your code in my child theme functions.php but still facing the same issue http://bubblz.in/test-2/ check the third row first product.(Added test product title for your ref)

Comment: Yes the filter is working on single product display page How to assign the same for category loop page. http://bubblz.in/test-2/

Comment: Yes that page displaying all the products from particular category, I have update the above code, still the 3rd row 1st product it is not working fine.

Comment: For testing myself added 5

Comment: This code doesnt have any effect

Comment: please check my update answer.

Comment: This code works when we click particular product and still nothing changed in http://bubblz.in/test-2/. Your code in functions targeting single product page.

Comment: then test-2 is not product category.

Comment: check my code again

Comment: Thanks buddy this is the exact code for adding except in title. The code is working fine.

Comment: glad to help you. :)

Comment: I just removed is_product() from the code so that the excerpt will be applicable to product category display loop.

Comment: ok. accept the answer if it works.